# About normalization in Redux

Tags: mongodb, redux

Assume you're making Reddit where each `Subreddit` has many `Post` and each `Post` has many `Comment`. Then the API response probably looks like this:

```
subreddits: [{
  title: "food"
  posts: [{
    id: "",
    body: "..",
    comments: [{
      id: ".."
      body: "..",
    }]
    ..morePosts
  },
  title: "culture"
  posts: [{
    id: "",
    body: "..",
    comments: [{
      id: ".."
      body: "..",
    }]
    ..morePosts
  },
]
```

But since Redux discourages such nested state, we normalize the data structure before we feed them into reducers. Then, the data can be represented like this:

```
subredditByTitle: {
  food: {
    id: subreddit_1,
    title: "food"
    posts: [post_1, post_2]
  }
  culture: {
    id: subreddit_2,
    title: "culture"
    posts: [post_3, post_4]
  }
}

postsById: {
  post_1: {
    body: ".."
    comments: [comment_1, comment_2]
  },
  post_2: {
    body: "..",
    comments: [comment_3, comment_4]
  }
}

commentsById: {
  comment_1: {
    body: ".."
  },
  comment_2: {
    body: ".."
  }
}
```

But it feels a bit awkward to normalize the backend data like this when I use MongoDB, especially when I am using `subdocuments`. In a relational DB, it makes sense to have a lookup table (e.g. `PostsById`) for every DB table, does it make sense to do the same for every DB collection? My gut feeling is that instead of trying to normalize everything, it might be better to have one reducer for each document, but I am not sure what the best practice might be.

Answer (score 1):

You should really normalize everything and have `entities` object in your store where you put all your entities. I tried many approaches but IMHO this is the only true way.

I am using it for things which would be unthinkable to do without this approach but they are out of scope of this answer other more common ones are pagination and [asking for data only when you need them](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/actions/index.js#L53) application feels super snappy when there is no unnecessary data loading.

I highly recommend to take a really good look at this tiny piece of [code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/reducers/index.js#L8-L14) and the redux real world example as whole there is really much to learn from that. Your `entities` reducer would look different obviously but you should be able to write your own to suit your needs

Comment: in resume, i starting to think that redux sucks a lot when you need to normalize document based data. The best benefit of developing using mongo is that you don't need this kind of normalization and treatment of the data (like joins, etc). Feels so bad using redux with mongo data...

Comment: @RenatoOliveira use Mobx instead ; )